# Let $u(x)$ be a $C^2$ solution to $-\Delta u(x)=|x|^2 \hspace{0.25cm} \text{ on } \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x)$ be a $C^2$ solution to $$-\Delta u(x)=|x|^2 \hspace{0.25cm} \text{ on } \mathbb{R}^n$$

- Show that $\Phi * |y|^2$ does not make sense.
- Find a solution nevertheless. Look for a polynomial.
- Set $m(r)= \mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}_{\partial B(0,r)} u(y)\,dS(y)$. Show that $$m(r)=u(0)+\dfrac{r^4}{4(n+2)}.$$

We "prove" previously,

> Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Assume that  \begin{equation*}
>  \begin{aligned} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)|(1+|y|)^{2-n}\,dy<\infty &
>  \hspace{1cm} \text{ for } n>3 \\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}
>  |f(y)|\ln(1+|y|)\,dy<\infty & \hspace{1cm}  \text{ for } n=2 \\
>  \end{aligned} \end{equation*} Prove that $u(x)=\Phi * f(x)\in
>  C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $-\Delta u(x)=f(x)$.

The first bullet, I think that the reason why it doesn't make sense is because when you use $f(y)=|y|^2$ both of these integrals diverge. Is this correct?

Also, I can't think of a polynomial that is a solution to this. Can I get some help?

Comment: Have you tried using spherical coordinates?

Comment: How so? What polynomial is associated with it?

Comment: This justification is close to correct. Note that the framed statement works only in one direction, so instead of looking at these integrals, you need to write down the definition of $\Phi * |y|^2$ and check that it doesn't converge.

Comment: It might be easier to first look for a polynomial solution to $- \Delta u = x_1^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Laplacian of $u$ to be a 2nd degree polynomial, we need $u$ to be a 4th degree polynomial. $u(x) = x_1^4+\dots+x_n^4$ does the job, up to a constant ($\Delta u = 12|x|^2$).

To prove the statement about $m(r)$, compute $m'(r)$ using the divergence theorem. Up to some constants, 
$$
m'(r) = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \int_{|x|<r}\Delta u = - \frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \int_{|x|<r} |x|^2 = -\frac{c_n}{r^{n-1}}\int_0^r t^2 t^{n-1}\,dt = -\frac{c_n}{r^{n-1}} \frac{r^{n+2}}{n+2}
$$
So the derivative is a multiple of $r^3$, hence the conclusion.

The function $u$ can't be obtained by convolving $|x|^2$ with the fundamental solution $|x|^{2-n}$ because the integral diverges: the contribution from scale $|x-y|\approx 2^k$ is about $2^{(n-1)k}$ (from volume) times  $2^{2k}$ (from the function) times $2^{(2-n)k}$ (from the kernel), totaling $ 2^{3k}$. Without computing this, one can observe that $|x|^{2-n}$ is already non-integrable at infinity, so it needs help to converge and $|x|^2$ is no help.